# How to use WebView full width

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

In my Windows Store App I have only a WebView in XAML:

```
<Grid SizeChanged="Grid_SizeChanged"
      Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <WebView x:Name="myWebView"
              Width="Auto"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto"/>
</Grid>
```

I want to set the width to the maximum available value on different screen sizes or orientations.

I've tried to get the width of the grit itself to set the with of the WebView. But the Grid give me only the width of the containing WebView (if set to any value). With Width="Auto", the width is zero. If I set the width of the WebView to 300, then the width of the Grid is also 300.

The height of the Grit is correct, and after a change of the orientation, I can set the height of the WebView to the Grit value. I want the same for the width.

How can I arrange that the WebView will use the available space?

Edit: Maybe a problem at loading content?

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        DetailParms parms = e.Parameter as DetailParms;
        //myWebView.Width = parms.webWidth;
        myWebView.NavigateToString(parms.html);
    }
```

I can set the WebView.Width with a value from parms. But at calling time I also do not know the available space.

Here is the complete XAML:

> ```
> <Page
>     x:Name="pageRoot"
>     x:Class="CTDICT.Programs.MemoDetails"
>     DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
>     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
>     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
>     xmlns:local="using:CTDICT.Programs"
>     xmlns:common="using:CTDICT.Common"
>     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
>     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
>     mc:Ignorable="d">
>
>
>     <Grid x:Name="myGrid"
>           SizeChanged="Grid_SizeChanged"
>           Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
>         <WebView x:Name="myWebView"
>                   ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto"/>
>     </Grid>
> </Page>
> ```

Comment: What's in `Grid_SizeChanged` ?

Comment: After adding x:Name "myGrid" to the Grid:
            Double test = myGrid.Width;
            test = this.Frame.Width;
In both cases: Result is NaN (Not a Number)

            Double test = myGrid.ActualWidth;
            test = this.Frame.ActualWidth;
In both cases: Width = 0.00

Comment: GridSizeChanged: myWebView.Height = e.NewSize.Height;

Answer (score 2):

Remove `Width="Auto"` from `WebView`. Don't give any width/height to any control. `Grid` will expand according to size and hence `WebView` also.

Comment: No. Without any width the resulting width is Zero!

Comment: Xyroid is right, please post all XAML (whats around the Grid)?

Comment: I can't format source code in a comment. But I will edit the complete Grid in my question above in a minute.

Comment: Without Setting the width for WebView I can see in Grid_SizeChanged e.NewSize.Width == 0. e.NewSize.Height is the correct Height according to the available space and is updated at a change of the orientation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why it is not working. But I can compute the remaining width and set the WebView.Width.

I do it in Grid_SizeChanged because it will be fired at orientation changes.

This code works for me now:

```
    private void Grid_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double remainingWidth = Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.Bounds.Width-362;
        myWebView.Width = remainingWidth;
        myWebView.Height = e.NewSize.Height;
    }
```

Interesting: After setting the WebView.Width here, Grid_SizeChanged is called again. The second time the e.NewSize.Width for the Grid is reflecting the WebSize.Width just changed before. This means, the Grid.Width is set after the WebView.Width has changed. Opposite to what Xyroid said and Rico Suter has confirmed.